# units for gdalwrap output extent

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, clip, bash

I am attempting to write a small bash script that will mass process a large number of raster `.tif` files. It should do the following:

1. Clip to a smaller extent
2. Reproject to UTM

This is what I have, so far:

```
ODIR="utm19"

if [ ! -d "$ODIR" ]; then
  mkdir $ODIR
fi

for i in `ls *.tif`;do
  gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:32718 \
  -te -80 -55 -15 -60 -te_srs EPSG:4326  \
  -r bilinear -wm 6048 -multi -srcnodata "-9999" \
  -srcnodata "-9999"  $i $ODIR/${i}.tif
done
```

However, I am a bit puzzled by the different opinions existing at:
http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html
vs.
§4.5 in http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/~smudd/TopoTutorials/html/tutorial_raster_conversion.html

So, what is the SRS units we should use for the `-te` option in `gdalwarp`

Comment: The GDAL documentation is correct and tutorial is wrong. If gis.stackexchange did not exist you could have tried it with a test image. Your usage with -te and -te_srs matches with GDAL documentation "in target SRS by default, or in the SRS specified with -te_srs".

Answer (score 1):

The GDAL documentation is correct and tutorial is wrong. In the tutorial the gdalwarp example is doing clipping without re-projection and the units of source and target are the same, so the values in the command are correct even if the author has been thinking that they are in source units.

The documentation is clear
https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-te

> **-te <xmin ymin xmax ymax>**
>
> Set georeferenced extents of output file to be created (in target SRS
> by default, or in the SRS specified with -te_srs)